# json_decode, foreach only return one row from json string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, foreach

In my "cart" table "items" column I store **json_encoded** strings. I decode, loop trough and grab them as an array. It works fine as long as the items has different product ID-s:

`[{"id":"56","size":"Small","quantity":"1"},{"id":"53","size":"Medium","quantity":"2"}]`

But when the items have the same product ID it only shows the last one in the json string,
in this case "Large":

`[{"id":"53","size":"Small","quantity":"1"},{"id":"53","size":"Large","quantity":"2"}]`

I made a **var_dump** for the products and it says that the two items are there, but like I said it only shows the last one in the output.

```
$txn_id = sanitize((int)$_GET['txn_id']);
$txnQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM transactions_alternative WHERE id = '{$txn_id}'");
$txn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($txnQuery);
$cart_id = $txn['cart_id'];
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
$items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
$idArray = array();
$products = array();var_dump($items);
foreach($items as $item){
   $idArray[] = $item['id'];
}
$ids = implode(',',$idArray);
$productQ = $db->query("SELECT i.id as 'id', i.title as 'title', c.id as 'cid', c.category as 'child', p.category as 'parent'
   FROM products i
   LEFT JOIN categories c ON i.categories = c.id
   LEFT JOIN categories p ON c.parent = p.id
   WHERE i.id IN ({$ids})");
  while($p =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ)){

    foreach($items as $item){
      if($item['id'] == $p['id']){
        $x = $item;
        continue;
      }
    }
    $products[] = array_merge($x,$p);var_dump($products);
   }
 ?>
<h2 class="text-center">Rendelés részletei</h2>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h3 class="text_center">Rendelt termékek</h3>
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Rendelt mennyiség</th><th>Termék neve</th><th>Kategória</th><th>Opció</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$product['quantity'];?> db</td>
      <td><?=$product['title'];?></td>
      <td><?=$product['parent'].' / '.$product['child'];?></td>
      <td><?=$product['size'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwritting `$x`

Replace

```
$x = $item;
```

with

```
$x[] = $item;
```

And initialize `$x = [];` before the foreach loop;

Comment: If I replace $x = $item with $x[] = $item; I get Undefined index: for quantity and size. What do you mean exactly by "initialize $x = [];" ?

Comment: what version of php are you using? if you are using an older version than 7.0 you will have to initalize the variable as `$x = array();`

Comment: I'm using 5.6. Okay, I see but before which foreach loop? And what happens is I switch to php 7.1.7? Do I have to use arrays?

Comment: The issue here is that `$x` is different now. You need to debug and see why `array_merge` isn't giving you the correct data.

Comment: I made a var_dump: `$products[] = array_merge($x,$p);var_dump($x);` It only shows one item. But if i do a var_dump "$products = array();" it shows the two item. So for some reason $x is only giving me just one item from the string